# Comparing the first day of "commented" statecategory with the first day of "approved" statecategory using "submittedat"?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the average of the first commented day vs the first approved day of this data set. I've narrowed it down to one PR that I'd like to work on but I'd like to have the query ultimately scale to the entire data set.

| pullRequest | stateCategory | submittedAt | refreshedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GitHub-microsoft-deepspeed-3324 | Commented | April 20, 2023, 9:59 PM | April 22, 2023, 5:28 PM |
| GitHub-microsoft-deepspeed-3324 | Commented | April 20, 2023, 10:30 PM | April 22, 2023, 5:28 PM |
| GitHub-microsoft-deepspeed-3324 | Commented | April 20, 2023, 10:32 PM | April 22, 2023, 5:28 PM |
| GitHub-microsoft-deepspeed-3324 | Commented | April 20, 2023, 10:53 PM | April 22, 2023, 5:28 PM |
| GitHub-microsoft-deepspeed-3324 | Approved | April 20, 2023, 11:37 PM | April 22, 2023, 5:28 PM |

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT "vcs_PullRequestReview"."pullRequest"
     , "vcs_PullRequestReview"."stateCategory"
     , "vcs_PullRequestReview"."submittedAt"
     , "vcs_PullRequest"."refreshedAt" 
FROM "vcs_PullRequestReview"
JOIN "vcs_PullRequest" 
  ON "vcs_PullRequestReview"."pullRequest" = "vcs_PullRequest"."id"
WHERE "vcs_PullRequest"."id" IN ('GitHub|microsoft|deepspeed|3324')
GROUP BY "vcs_PullRequestReview"."pullRequest"
       , "vcs_PullRequestReview"."stateCategory"
       , "vcs_PullRequestReview"."submittedAt"
       , "vcs_PullRequest"."refreshedAt" 
ORDER BY "vcs_PullRequestReview"."pullRequest" DESC
       , "vcs_PullRequestReview"."submittedAt" ASC
```

I know it's probably a window function or a series of case statement and subqueries but I'm not sure how to put it together. Thank you!

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think probably the easiest thing you can do is to utilize a CTE to prepare a mapping ("pullRequest", "stateCategory") -> minimum submittedAt and then use this to find what you want:

```sql
with minSubmittedAtByPR as (
  select pullRequest, stateCategory, min(submittedAt) as minSubmittedAt
  from vcs_PullRequestReview
  group by pullRequest, stateCategory
)
select pr.pullRequest, minCommented.minSubmittedAt as minCommentedAt, minApproved.minSubmittedAt as minApprovedAt 
from vcs_PullRequest pr
left join minSubmittedAtByPR minCommented
on pr.id = minCommented.pullRequest and minCommented.stateCategory = 'Commented'
left join minSubmittedAtByPR minApproved
on pr.id = minApproved.pullRequest and minApproved.stateCategory = 'Approved';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question if *days* refers to calendar days or 24 hour intervals. The following query returns the mean interval between first comment and first approval:

```
WITH pr(pull_request, state_category, submitted_at, refreshed_at) AS
  (VALUES ('GitHub-microsoft-deepspeed-3324', 'Commented','2023-04-20 21:59'::timestamp, '2023-04-22 17:28'::timestamp),
          ('GitHub-microsoft-deepspeed-3324', 'Commented','2023-04-20 22:30'::timestamp, '2023-04-22 17:28'::timestamp),
          ('GitHub-microsoft-deepspeed-3324', 'Commented','2023-04-20 22:32'::timestamp, '2023-04-22 17:28'::timestamp),
          ('GitHub-microsoft-deepspeed-3324', 'Commented','2023-04-20 22:53'::timestamp, '2023-04-22 17:28'::timestamp),
          ('GitHub-microsoft-deepspeed-3324', 'Approved','2023-04-20 23:37'::timestamp, '2023-04-22 17:28'::timestamp)),
pr_spans AS       
  (SELECT pr.pull_request,
          MIN(pr.submitted_at) FILTER (WHERE pr.state_category = 'Commented') AS first_commented_at,
          MIN(pr.submitted_at) FILTER (WHERE pr.state_category = 'Approved') AS first_approved_at
     FROM pr
    GROUP BY pr.pull_request)
SELECT AVG(pr_spans.first_approved_at - pr_spans.first_commented_at) AS mean_first_comment_to_first_approval
  FROM pr_spans;
```

The mean can be expressed as fractional days (24 hour itervals) by changing the final `SELECT` expression to:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM AVG(pr_spans.first_approved_at - pr_spans.first_commented_at)) / 86400 AS mean_first_comment_to_first_approval
```

To get the mean as fractional calendar days based on integral calendar days per pull request, cast `pr.submitted_at` in the `pr_spans` subquery to dates; e.g., `pr.submitted_at::date`.